# Can you make a flexbox child expand to fit parent but not contents?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm using a `flexbox` to make a div take up the remaining vertical space in the browser window, but I'd like to prevent it from expanding beyond that.  When its contents exceed its vertical size, I'd like a scrollbar to show up in the flexbox child that is now too small.

Is this possible? Or is there some other layout technique I should be using for this?

Here's a link to a JSFiddle to show the situation: https://jsfiddle.net/83990d3a/

The other vertical space is taken up with a toolbar, the exact vertical size of which is not known beforehand.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just add `overflow: auto` to `#content` ([updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0t3bymem/)):

```
#content {
    background-color: #ceecf5;
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Safari, though. Any ideas for that?

Comment: It's pretty basic and standard css, so I'm pretty sure it's not the problem.  Safari version up to and including 8 need the -webkit- prefix for flexbox properties.