# Flex box fill parent, but don't stretch parent on overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is a similar question to *[Can you make a flexbox child expand to fit parent but not contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640224/can-you-make-a-flexbox-child-expand-to-fit-parent-but-not-contents)*, however, that solution doesn't work for me.

I have a layout such that the whole page should always fit on screen (between header and footer), and if contents is too large, then its container should scroll. (Basically the last example from: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

I already tried the solution from the question I linked above:

```
#chat {
    background-color: #ceecf5;
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

But the parent is still being stretched off the page.

If I set a manual height to `#chat` it works correctly, but then it only fits correctly for the screen size I made it on, so I want an automatic height.

```css
#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  min-width: 300px;
  flex: 1;
}
#header {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
}
#column-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.column {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: aqua;
}
#chat {
  background-color: #ceecf5;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
#main-column {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: azure;
}
#footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="column-flex-container">
    <div class="column side-column">
      <div id="chat">
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main-column" class="column"></div>
    <div class="column side-column"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dmn3gLz4/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few problem items to consider:

### `min-height: 100vh`

You wrote:

> > I have a layout such that the whole page should always fit on screen (between header and footer), and if contents is too large, then its container should scroll.

Then you shouldn't set the height on the `body` element to `min-height: 100vh`.

With `min-height` you're allowing the element to expand from that point on. Use `height: 100vh`.

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  /* min-height: 100vh; */
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh; /* establish fixed height */
}
```

---

### `flex-flow: row wrap-reverse`

If you're trying to build a three-column layout, there's no need for horizontal wrapping.

To reverse the order of the columns, use `row-reverse` not `wrap-reverse`.

```
#column-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-flow: row wrap-reverse; */
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-flow: row-reverse nowrap; /* OR, just...
  flex-direction: row-reverse; */
}
```

---

### `flex-shrink: 1`

Your header and footer each have `height: 50px`. But because they are flex items, and flex items can shrink by default (`flex-shrink: 1`), the header and footer are shrinking. To keep the 50px heights, disable shrink (`flex-shrink: 0`, or just use `flex: 0 0 50px`). [More details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)...

---

### syntax error

You have an errant closing div. Consider removing it.

```
        <div id="main-column" class="column"></div>
        <div class="column side-column"></div>
    </div>
<!-- </div> -->  <-- STRAY CLOSING TAG
<div id="footer"></div>
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dmn3gLz4/3/)

```css
#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  min-width: 300px;
  flex: 1;
}
#header {
  /* height: 50px; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 50px; /* new */
}
#column-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-flow: row wrap-reverse; */
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.column {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: aqua;
}
#chat {
  background-color: #ceecf5;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
#main-column {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: azure;
}
#footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  flex-shrink: 0; /* new */
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh; /* adjusted */
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="column-flex-container">
    <div class="column side-column">
      <div id="chat">
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
        <div class="message">Sender: Message</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main-column" class="column"></div>
    <div class="column side-column"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- </div> -->
  <div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this, it was very helpful.

Comment: using 100vh only works if you are at the root. Once you are somewhere else it will break... fragile solution.